# Creating Footer Read

Tags: header-footer

I would like to create a footer in pdfLaTeX.
The footnote should look like this:

[image: Footnote]

On the left it should show the current page number, in the middle a description and on the right side an image.

I tried till now the following:

```
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    ...
    \lfoot{\thepage}
    \cfoot{some kind of description}
    \rfoot{\includegraphics{pictures//image1}}
```

but i don't know how to get the background colored.
Any suggestions?:)

Comment: Can it be you mean »footer« (i.e. the area at the bottom of a page) when you say »footnote«?

Comment: Yes indeed. Is there any difference between `footer` and `footnote`?

Comment: A footnote is something different, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footnote

Comment: I changed the description :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\cfoot{%
  \colorbox{yellow}{%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\thepage\hfill some description \includegraphics{..}}%
  }%
}
```

Comment: Working pretty good! Thanks! But how can i center `some decription` ?:)

Comment: @Leviathan -- inside the box, make the pieces on the end have "no width" -- `{\rlap{\thepage}\hfill some description\hfill \llap{\includegraphics{...}}}`

Comment: Got one more question.. how can i make the Text (page number and some description..) center vertically?